# Facebook Messenger Chat Plugin Not Showing Guest Mode Webflow

Tags: facebook, plugins, chat, facebook-messenger-bot

Facebook Messenger Chat Plugin not showing 'Guest' mode on my `webflow` website. I have put the code in my `webflow` website but no result is shown.

I have a problem on `webflow` where I want to integrate Facebook Chat messenger plugin. The problem is that the Plugin is not showing 'Guest' mode as It should be. I have checked the setup and enabled the guest mode but I have no luck on this.

[image]

You can see in the image above. It only shows 'Login' but no 'Guest' mode. I am not able to figure out the problem. If someone has the solution, please let me know.

Code:

```
<!-- Messenger Chat Plugin Code -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
    <div id="fb-customer-chat" class="fb-customerchat">
    </div>

    <script>
      var chatbox = document.getElementById('fb-customer-chat');
      chatbox.setAttribute("page_id", "250164938373160");
      chatbox.setAttribute("attribution", "biz_inbox");
    </script>

    <!-- Your SDK code -->
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v19.0'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, I tried many different ways but all failed. I tried accessing some websites that use chat plugins and as a result they also encountered problems. Ultimately I think this error is due to facebook's api server.

Comment: yeh, I have tried all the things but the problem is not fixed yet. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Not long ago I was still able to use the chat as a guest but now it seems like everyone is having this error. If it's because of Facebook, we can't do anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Facebook made comment that they had to stop the guest button from the chat plugin, this was due to a security concern. Facebook advised they will likely put the guest button back on after they've addressed the security concern.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).